# Franciscan apostolic college governance

Tags: catholicism, canon-law, missions, religious-orders

The Franciscan apostolic college of [San Fernando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_of_San_Fernando_de_Mexico) in Mexico staffed the missions of California, then resembling an [apostolic prefecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostolic_prefect).

Since it was a Franciscan college they presumably owed some kind of allegiance to the [Order of Friars Minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_Friars_Minor) in Assisi. I'm not sure if the college would have interacted with the Archdiocese of Mexico.

The head of the college was called a Guardian. Did he follow a Franciscan rule book separate from canon law? Did he report to any superior?